# Is JQuery event.which broken?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, mousemove

According to the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), `event.which` is supposed to return **1** if the user was pressing the left mouse button at the time of the event.

However, the whole mouse-button-pressed logic seems to be broken for Firefox and Internet Explorer. Please see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MjG8p/) that outputs the value of `event.which` using a `mousemove` event.

The JSFiddle will demonstrate that Firefox (24.0) and Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.16384) always return the value **1** whatever button you pressed *or* did not press.

### Question time!

Am I the only one experiencing this issue and if not, is it a bug in JQuery?

Can you think of a workaround? In my application, I need to know the correct value of event.which and I need to parse that from an mousemove event handler that is attached to the window object.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's dependant on the browser which values they provide for the event. If a `1` is all jQuery gets, that's what it shows. You could try `event.button` as that is native, but be aware it's zero based, so `0` = left, `1` = middle and `2` = right click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect `event.which` to work for events involving a click such as `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `click`, for example.

If you need this information during a mouse move, you would have to pre-record it during one of these other events and use it when you detect the move.

http://jsfiddle.net/RDNzS/

The fragility of this, as always, is if a click event happens outside of your target area (such as not even in a browser) as you won't find out about that.

Comment: Given your feedback, I made another [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kk45X/) that demonstrates a workaround. Thus you've answered half of my questions, the most important one and I'll accept your answer. Thank you very much! Hopefully, you or someone else have the knowledge or will to find out what exactly is causing this behavior and whether or not that is to be treated as a bug in JQuery. Perhaps I'll return to this issue myself in the future.